# KVM vm machine is not booting up after image size increased

Tags: qemu, kvm, libvirt

KVM vm is not booting up after I have made the below changes.

Environment:-

```
qemu-img version 2.1.3
ubuntu VM
```

```
1. Stop the VM
2. qemu-img resize vm1.img +50G
3. start the VM
```

vm1 is not booting up & but IPaddress able to ping from other server.
`var/log/libvirt/qemu# vm1.log`

```
2022-07-06 09:25:51.311+0000: shutting down
2022-07-07 05:33:14.360+0000: starting up
LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none /usr/bin/qemu-kvm -name vm1 -S -machine pc-i440fx-2.1,accel=kvm,usb=off -cpu host -m 32768 -realtime mlock=off -smp 4,sockets=4,cores=1,threads=1 -uuid 25da0d89-4249-41ae-baab-5282d1531ef7 -nographic -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/vm1.monitor,server,nowait
```

kindly help me to fix this problem

Comment: Hover over the virtual-machine tag and read the last line.

Comment: Sorry i can't understand what you are referring, can you please tell me in detail

Comment: Quoting the tag: ONLY QUESTIONS ABOUT PROGRAMMING ARE ON-TOPIC.